# Android Set FAB Behavior for ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, floating-action-button

I'm currently developing an application which have a `ListView` and a `FAB`. Now what i want to do is hide the FAB on the beginning and then show it after my ListView is scroll down. I have my `content_main.xml` where the ListView is coded, and `activity_main.xml` where my FAB is.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_up" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
          <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/words_list_view"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my `Main_Activity.java` i have onScrollListener where i'am stock, thinking that this is where i can handle the behavior of FAB.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }
            int preLast;
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if (lastItem > 20) {
                    if (preLast != lastItem) { 
                    // SHow FAB Here
                    }
                } else {
                    // Hide FAB Here
                }
            }

        });
```

I hope you guys understand my problem. Thank You Very Much! Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem? All you need to do is call [`hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#hide%28%29) or [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#show%28%29) on your `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: Umm. the problem is  i don't know if showing or hiding the FAB with my onScrollistener is the correct way, i'v search for this FAB Behavior, and i found that the FAB is reacting on scroll but not onScrollListener with ListView, also i havent found yet about FAB Behavior for ListView, theyre always using the RecycleView, but mine is ListView and i don't know how to do it on ListView.